# Names for special submatrices?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Let $(a_{ij}), i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$ be a matrix. What are the names for the following special square submatrices:

- for any set of indices $J⊂{1,2,..,n}$, the submatrix 
  $(a_{jk})j,k\in J$,
- a submatrix formed by removing the last m rows and last m columns;
- a submatrix formed by removing any m rows and any m columns.

Does a principal submatrice mean any of the above three kinds? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first kind is a principal submatrix, the second kind is a leading principal submatrix, and the last kind is just any old submatrix. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Why do you call the last one "old"?

Comment: It's just an idiom, not a mathematical definition.

Comment: http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/any-old